# Set new state to an existing array state

Tags: javascript, react-native

If I have a state that looks like this

```
this.state = {
names: [
"Snap, Crackle, Pop"
]
}
```

Is it possible to create a new state by referring to an index number of an existing array?

Something like this is suppose? This is just an example.

```
this.state = {
names: [
"Snap, Crackle, Pop"
],
myName: this.state.names[0]
}
```

Comment: why not just store the index `0` instead?

Comment: First of all, no, unless the variable already exists. Plus, `this.state.names` only has a single element, you want `["Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"]` instead.

Comment: @Federkun that's true, but i suposse he will change by array of name's, so needs to setState when recive props

Comment: I'd do `const names = ["Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"];` and `this.state = { names, myName: names[0] };`

Comment: not sure I would want to derive state from state tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set it in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { names, myName } = this.state;
  if (!myName) this.setState({ myName: names[0] });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. But you could just store the index that allow you to refer to the `names` later.

```
this.state = {
  names: [
    "Snap, Crackle, Pop"
  ],
  myName: 0
}
```

is a better choice. Then

```
get thisIsMyName() {
  return this.state.names[this.state.myName]
}
```

when you want to refer to the actual name.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest and most convenient way is that you can refer to existing / previous state by:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  myName: prevState.names[0],
});
```

Another way would be to capture it into a variable, like:

```
const myName = this.state.names[0];
this.setState({ myName });
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this question is about initializing state, not changing it.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I read the sentence "Is it possible to create a **new state** by referring to an index number of an existing array?" and understood it wrong. Also the headline / question is very misleading